# past modal should + the adverb never

Tags: word-order, negation

I've found all alternatives and wonder which one is grammatically correct?

1. I should have *never* told you that.
2. I should *never* have told you that.
3. I *never* should have told you that.

Comment: In my dialect, #3 is most commonly used.  #1 is in second place. And #2  is in third place.

Comment: This is a valid question. For non native speakers, the order of the words is troubling. +1

Comment: @TRomano strange...in InE, it's the second at first! I advise to my kid million times a day -*"Hey, you should never do that!"*

Comment: @Maulik V: Do you say "You should never have done that" or "You should have never done that" or "You never should have done that"?

Comment: yes, 'you should never have...' is what I use. @TRomano

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of style. While I prefer saying/writing 'should never have...' others (like TRomano) may prefer 'never should have'. And neither makes it a wrong choice.

Google NGram shows results of all those three styles, ['should never have'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=should%20have%20never%2C%20should%20never%20have%2C%20never%20should%20have&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshould%20have%20never%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshould%20never%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnever%20should%20have%3B%2Cc0) being most frequently used.

[Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22should%20never%20have%20done%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22should%20never%20have%20done%22&tbm=nws) of news on the usage 'should never have'

Answer (score -1):

You must always place the negation(i.e never) as close as possible to the verb. Though all the three forms are used, in my opinion, the first one is the best. I'm sure it is grammatically correct.

Ex: I should have **never done** that.
    You must **never do** that.